# How Can I use JavaScriptChannel in Flutter inappwebview's MyChromeSafariBrowser option?

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-inappwebview

I am a junior Flutter engineer who is working in South Korea!
I have an issue concerning my project.
It would be greatly appreciated if you could share the solution to this particular problem(or anything similar to this).

My Question: I want to use JavaScriptChannel in MyChromeSafariBrowser() of Flutter inappwebview package. Is it possible to use JavaScriptChannel in this?

Some might suggest that InAppBrowser,HeadlessInAppWebView,InAppWebView might be an option, but however, I cannot access/utilize in my circumstance.

[Agreement Page for sharing the private data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvIAZ.png)

What's the purpose of this HTML Source: We link the specific webpage to get agreement for using the privacy data. Users input their signature, and enter the confirm button. Then

**JavaScriptChannel Code**

```
   // webview -> send data to the app
    function send_agree_result(result) {
      // distinguish IOS or Android
      var isMobile = {
        Android: function () {
          return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) == null ? false : true;
        },
        iOS: function () {
          return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i) == null ? false : true;
        },
        any: function () {
          return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.iOS());
        }
      };

      if (isMobile.any()) {
        if (isMobile.Android()) {
          window.bridge.sendResultAgree(result);      // 안드로이드(android)
        } else if (isMobile.iOS()) {
          webkit.messageHandlers.sendResultAgree.postMessage(result);   // 아이폰(ios)
        }
      }
   }
```

This JavascriptChannel function will be operated. And the App can get 'yes or no' from website. Then the next step will be started in the App.

**Flutter inappwebview Code**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';


void GeneAgreeView({String id}){
  final ChromeSafariBrowser browser = MyChromeSafariBrowser();
  InAppWebViewController webViewController;
  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();
  ChromeSafariBrowserClassOptions options = ChromeSafariBrowserClassOptions(

      android: AndroidChromeCustomTabsOptions(addDefaultShareMenuItem: true),
      ios: IOSSafariOptions(barCollapsingEnabled: true,

      ));
  PullToRefreshController pullToRefreshController = PullToRefreshController(
    options: PullToRefreshOptions(
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    onRefresh: () async {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        webViewController?.reload();
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
        webViewController?.loadUrl(
            urlRequest: URLRequest(url: await webViewController?.getUrl()));
      }
    },
  );
  browser.open(
      url: Uri.parse("https://www.my-genomestory.com/agreements/index/bestf/?service=genome&clientKey=$id&machine=app"),

      options: ChromeSafariBrowserClassOptions(
          android: AndroidChromeCustomTabsOptions(addDefaultShareMenuItem: false),
          ios: IOSSafariOptions(barCollapsingEnabled: true)));

}

class MyChromeSafariBrowser extends ChromeSafariBrowser {

  @override
  void onOpened() {
    print("ChromeSafari browser opened");
  }

  @override
  void onCompletedInitialLoad() {
    print("Chrome")}
```